# What's this stupid thing about having to indent all of your code with 4 spaces for it to be rendered as code?

Tags: feature-request, code-formatting

isn't there some markup hook that i can use to do that?

i'm getting tired of fetching some old C file that i want to simply paste in and having to manually add spaces to **many** of the lines.

this seems silly.

r b-j

Comment: Use a proper IDE and go ctrl-A tab and you're done. :-)

Comment: used to be ctrl-].

Comment: you mean `command-mode >`.

Answer (score 4):

You could do:

```
<pre>
code
code2
code3
</pre>
```

which gives you

```
code
code2
code3
```

I think triple backticks `code` should work to:

````
```
code
more code
some final code
```
````

`code
more code
some final code`

This should also work:

```
<code>
code
code2
code3
</code>
```

which renders as:

`code
code2
code3`

The `<pre>` tag has trouble with HTML special characters `<` and `>`:

```
<pre>
#include <limits.h>
</pre>
```

gives:

```
#include
```

Comment: i'll give it a try.

Comment: the <pre> tag is the way to go

Comment: The triple-backtick works in desktop, but mis-renders without line breaks on mobile

Comment: please tell me you don't have a `class pre; std::vector<pre> prepositions_vector;` in your C++...

Comment: @OlliNiemitalo no, seriously, I'll make this answer a community wiki. Please add an example for what doesn't work!

Answer (score 1):

In fact, just use the curly braces when answering: the SE answer "IDE" has this function automatically. Just hit the curly brace button after selecting the code you want indented.

[image]

Comment: Peter, i cut and pasted text from an old C file into the SE window, but i wanted this text to look like code.  best that i understand, every line (even the blank lines) has to have a tab or 4 spaces preceding anything else.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson: The curly braces button does do that for you, is there something I'm missing?

Comment: maybe it's something i am missing.  i'll fiddle with it again.